# sed command to delete leading 91 if number is 12 digit

Tags: text-processing, sed, numeric-data

sed command to delete leading 91 if number is 12 digit

My file is

```
919876543210
917894561230
9194561230
```

Need output

```
9876543210
7894561230
9194561230
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -e '/^91[0-9]\{10\}$/s/^91//' < input > output
```

(or use filename if you prefer)

Comment: Why match first and substitute later? Why not just `sed -s 's/^91\([0-9]\{10\}\)/\1/'`?

Comment: I tend to avoid decorated brackets unless they are essential, and I thought it looked complicated enough already! Hence the solution given.
I was going for clarity.

P.S. Did you really mean -s ? Only asking because if you didn't, it might be a bit confusing for readers.

Comment: Fair enough, although in that case I'd have used the almost (just as?) portable `sed -Ee 's/^91([0-9]{10})/\1/'`. I know the `-E` is supported by GNU sed, BSD sed and at elast my Arch's version of busybox `sed`. I don't know which, if any, sed implementations don't support it.

Comment: Yes, that would work too, although I still think the simple solution I have given is inherently clearer to readers who have not encountered those constructs.

Comment: You may be right. It seems far harder to understand to me, but to each their own.

Comment: "On lines that start with 91 followed by 10 digits, strip off the leading 91" vs "replace lines starting with 91 (and 10 digits) with (those 10 digits)"

Comment: Terdon 's regex would just need an anchoring `$`